# Batch File Deletion

Tags: file, batch-file, if-statement, delete-file

How am I able to make a batch file with an `If not` command, such as: `IF NOT [extension type] Then delete all` in a folder?

Answer (score 2):

The `for` command combined with an `if` command and variable expansion can be used to delete all files except those with the specified extension. For example, this will delete all files in the current directory that do not have a .TXT extension (case insensitive):

```
for %%i in (*) do (
    if /i "%%~xi" neq ".TXT" del %%i
)
```

Comment: Just be careful what folder you run this in.